# How to find surface area using gaussian quadrature method in python, which is accomplished by tessellating or meshing the coordinates

Tags: python, gaussian, brute-force

I am new to python and basically from mechanical background, So i feel it difficult to solve it. kindly help me in this issue.

I have coordinates Xs, Ys, Zs, each having some set of random points. Say 20 each

The coordinates have to be meshed or tessellated within Xs, Ys and Zs.

Then using Gaussian quadrature method or Brute force method we should find the area of each element and sum up to get the total area.

I have went through many references but couldn't find any especially to find the area.

Can anyone help me out in getting a code which can do the above stated.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [scipy integrate module](http://www.scipy.org/doc/api_docs/SciPy.integrate.quadrature.html), which has a quadrature function